# Split string in Dynamic ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++

I want to split string.

## 1 appears empty string

## 2 missing zeros;

if my code:

```
Question #1
    value = "001#$002#$003";
    strList = strsplit(value,"#$");
    result: "001", "", "002", "", "003";
    //if i using spliter like "$" it is ok. result:  "001", "002","003";
    
    Question #2
    str2con(value,"#$");
    result: "1", "2","3" missing zeros
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the second question itself might be useful for someone else.

str2con_RU(value,"#$");

Answer (score 7):

Take a close look at the documentation of the [Global::strSplit Method [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.strsplit.aspx) and [Global::str2con Method [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.str2con.aspx). The remarks section contains the answer to your questions:

Remarks of `strSplit` documentation (emphasis by me):

> **Each** character in the _delimiter string is used to split the _stringToSplit parameter.

So you should call `strSplit` first with either # or $ and then remove the other symbol with `strReplace`.

Remarks of `str2con` method (emphasis by me):

> In the _convertNumericToInt64 parameter, a value of true indicates **the returned contents will be converted to an int64 value if they only have numeric characters**.A value of false indicates that the returned values will not be converted to an int64 value and String values will always be returned. **The default value of the _convertNumericToInt64parameter is true.**

So no need to go all russian with `str2con_RU` :)